# Header location do php está inserindo arquivo em vez de redirecionar

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Quando realizo o login no meu formulário, após a verificação se o usuário é válido deveria haver o redirecionamento para a página home. Porém ao utilizar `header('location: home.php');` está sendo inserido o conteúdo da página home.php na página de login. Estou utilizando o seguinte método em ajax para enviar os dados para o php.

```
function loginRequest() {

 // Declaração de Variáveis
 var delay = 3;
 var usuario   = document.getElementById("txtusuario").value;
 var senha   = document.getElementById("txtsenha").value;
 var btnrqlogin   = document.getElementById("btnrqlogin").id;
 var result = document.getElementById("resultado");
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

 // Exibi a imagem de progresso
 result.innerHTML = '<img id="loading-icon" src="./images/eclipse.gif"/>';

 setTimeout(function(){
  // Iniciar uma requisição
  xmlreq.open("GET", "./controllers/controller.php?txtusuario=" + usuario + "&txtsenha=" + senha + "&btnrqlogin=" + btnrqlogin, true);

  // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de ado
  xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){

     // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
     if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {

        // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
        if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
           result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;
        }else{
           result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
        }
     }
  };
  xmlreq.send(null);
}, delay*1000);
 }
```

Esse é o meu código php.

```
$usuario = $_GET["txtusuario"];
    $senha = $_GET["txtsenha"];

    //Chama arquivo de conexao com o banco
    require_once("../inc/database.php");

    $consulta = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT id, nome, email FROM tb_usuarios_agencia WHERE email=:email AND senha = :senha");
    $consulta->bindParam(':email', $usuario);
    $consulta->bindParam(':senha', $senha); 
    $consulta->execute();

    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $linha['id'];
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];

        header('location: home.php');
    }
```

Formulário HTML.

```
<div id="resultado">

</div>
<form id="sign_in">
                    <div class="msg">Faça login para iniciar sua sessão</div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtusuario" name="txtusuario" placeholder="Usuário" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtsenha" name="txtsenha" placeholder="Senha" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8 p-t-5">
                            <a href="forgot-password.html">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <!-- onclick="loginRequest();" -->
                            <button id="btnrqlogin" class="btn btn-block bg-pink waves-effect" name="btnrqlogin" onclick="loginRequest();" type="button">ACESSAR</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Você não está usando ajax? o redirecionamento não devia ser feito pelo javascript, em vez de colocar na tag result

Comment: É a primeira vez que utilizo o ajax para enviar os dados para o php, não sei como fazer esse redirecionamento pelo javascript.

Comment: window.location.href = "home.php"; ou window.location.replace("home.php");

Comment: A menos se você estiver usando codeigniter ou laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requisições Ajax direcionadas a uma `div`, irão encher essa `div` com o retorno. Logo, fazer um redirecionamento no retorno do Ajax, irá apenas encher essa `div` com o conteúdo da página retornada.

Tentar retornar `<script>` do Ajax não resolve, pois ele não será executado, virá apenas como string.

Para contornar isso, retorne do Ajax apenas o código JavaScript e execute usando `eval()`. No PHP mude o `header('location: home.php');` código para:

```
echo 'location.href="home.php"';
```

E no Ajax, mude o `result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;` para:

```
eval(xmlreq.responseText);
```

Comment: Agora deu certo, muito obrigado!